# String to String[] - Apache

Tags: java, string

I am a student and I am new to programming in java. I have a problem with this code (which I did not write) that I was found, I wanted to know if possible, not knowing very well the apache library, if you could get one back from this method String [] s instead of a single string.

```
public static String getString() throws IOException {
    String content = null;
    File folder = new File("E:\\Result.txt");
    content = FileUtils.readFileToString(folder) + "\n";
    String remainingString = content.substring(content.indexOf("["),
            content.lastIndexOf("]") + 1);
    // System.out.println(remainingString);
    return remainingString;

}
```

For clarity the content of Result.txt is a string. (For example [-8,6,1] [4,10,-1] [7,-5,3] [10,-8,3] [10,-8,-6]). And My Problem is that: I wish I maintain this the same format of the string (in result.txt) but use it with a string [] array. thank you very much

Comment: Fundamentally, you are having this problem because at some point you were wondering how to read a string from a file, and instead of actually learning how to do it by reading appropriate tutorials and documentation and experimenting, you simply grabbed a code snippet that you didn't understand. And now you are lost when you need to make a change. You need to show us your current attempt. If you are having a specific problem after that, feel free to come back. As it stands, it's not really clear what you are looking for, and we won't do your coding for you (because we want you to learn).

Comment: What result do you want?  Do you want a `String[]` with one element?  If not, you need to be clear about what you're trying to accomplish, and specifically what you want the array contents to look like.  (After you read appropriate tutorials and try something yourself and post your attempt, that is.)

Comment: Looking at the sample, I think what you actually need is to turn the string into a 2 dimensional integer array `int[][]`. Is that correct?

Comment: my attempt is already trying to run the piece of code. And i have already read the javadoc about the split. But the problem arises when I try this: 

    public static String[] arg() throws IOException {
  String[] strArray = getString().split(" ");
  // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
  return strArray;

 }

Comment: @theblitz We are not mindreaders.  So far, you've said repeatedly that you want a `String[]` but have not told us you want the contents of the array to look like.  Now you've told us that your attempts have led to a problem, but you have not given us information about what that problem is.  Please give us something we can work with!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this

[String split method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get all the `[<content>]` blocks; then you just want to add them until you cannot read the next block:

```
public static String getString() throws IOException {
    File folder = new File("E:\\Result.txt"); // such a strange name for variable with text file
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(folder);
    List <String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
    int lastIndex = 0;
    while (lastIndex != -1) {
        int i1 = content.indexOf('[', lastIndex);
        int i2 = content.indexOf(']', lastIndex) + 1;
        if (i1 != -1 && i2 != 0) {
            strs.put(content.substr(i1, i2));
            lastIndex = i2;
        } else {
            lastIndex = -1;
        }
    }
    return strs.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Comment: i would have "[-8,6,1] [4,10,-1] [7,-5,3] [10,-8,3] [10,-8,-6] [5,-3,6] " (the content without quotes). but with the same spaces e brackets. thank you very much

Comment: Then I'm maybe misunderstood, what do you want to get here.

Please, add some concrete examples of what output you expect on some input or very **clear** problem description.

Comment: "E:\\Result.txt" not is a name for variable, but it is a path

Comment: For ecample another my program create a sequence of solution (result) in this form: 1)[-8,6,1] [4,10,-1] [7,-5,3] 2)[4,2,3] [-1,2,3] [4,3,1] [-2,3,-4] [4,2,1] [4,-2,3] [4,-3,1] [2,3,1] 3)[5,-2,3,-4,1] [-2,-1,7,3,-4] ecc ecc

Comment: Of course, it's path, but I'm wondering not about the pats itself (which, by the way, is better to keep in constant (`public static final`) member, not in the code), but about variable name: `folder`

Comment: I would like to be able to automatically extract the contents of a txt file into a String [], and NO String, and then not using the split because it was already creating problems

Comment: @theblitz Do you mean, that you get as input some file like http://pastebin.com/mgQpi9sN and want to get int[][] in output?

Comment: NO, i would have the same content of my file txt (that i have already in the form of String) but in a String[] array, but i have already try with split but it make me problem. thank you for all

Comment: I was trying your solution I've written before, but the "put" method reported an error. Do it require a library in Precise?